# Cannot set a variable's value inside cypress command cy.get() to use outside the command

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm setting a `pin` variable, updating it in `cy.get()` and then trying to use it after the `cy.get()` - it doesn't allow me to do this.

I've also read here that this is not possible: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values.

I really need to use this variable in order to be able to login: it's a generated PIN and I need to use it when logging in.

```
var pin = ""
cy.get('.pin-field').invoke('text').then((text1) => {
    pin = text1; //assign text1 value to global pin variable, does not work

    cy.log(text1) // this works and logs the value of text1
})

cy.log(pin) //this just logs an empty
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in synchronization: The function `invoke` returns a Promise, which is executed in async manner. The code `cy.log(pin)` is executed just right after the `invoke` is called and before the promise is resolved.

Try this:

```
cy.get('.pin-field').invoke('text').then(pin => {
    cy.log(pin);  
})
```

Or you can simulate synchronous behavior with `async/await`:

```
async function login(cy) {
    const pin = await cy.get('.pin-field').invoke('text'); // call it synchron
    cy.log(pin); // this code executes when 'invoke` returned
}
```

Don't forget, the code with `await` must be closed in an `async` function.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are struggling with the scope. What works for me is this:

```js
    cy.get('.original_object')
      .then($value => {
        const retreivedValue = $value.text()
    cy.get('.test_object')
      .should('contain', retreivedValue)
```