# How to return true or false when condition is satisfied in Cypress

Tags: cypress

```
isPackagePresent: function (packageTitle) {
 var res;
 cy.get(viewResultsPageObj.packagesContainer).each(($mediaPackage) => {
   cy.wrap($mediaPackage).within(() => {
    cy.get(viewResultsPageObj.packageTitle).then(($ele) => {
      let actualTitle = removeWhiteSpace($ele.text());
      if (actualTitle.includes(removeWhiteSpace(packageTitle))) {
        res = true;
        cy.log("insisde if");
        return;
       }
      });
     });
   });
  cy.log("res" + res);
  cy.log("end");
  }
```

In the above snippet, when the if condition matches then it prints "insisde if" but never executes "return" (does not go out of the each loop) and never sets the value of "res" variable to true. So for each row in the data table, this function is executed and within the function - I am just trying to iterate through "viewResultsPageObj.packagesContainer" elements and if a condition is satisfied then stop iterating and come out of this function by either returning true or false. Any thoughts? Thanks

Tried different ways but nothing helped. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot set a variable's value inside cypress command cy.get() to use outside the command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062989/cannot-set-a-variables-value-inside-cypress-command-cy-get-to-use-outside-the)

Comment: I can do everything inside then, but I am trying to get a text through a function which can be called somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

To make the `cy.log()` work in your example, you need to wait for the Cypress queue to complete before accessing `res`.

To do so, wrap the code using `res` in a `cy.then()`.

```js
let res;

cy.get(viewResultsPageObj.packagesContainer).each(($mediaPackage) => {
  ...
  if (actualTitle.includes(removeWhiteSpace(packageTitle))) {
    res = true;
  }
  ...
})

cy.then(() => {
  cy.log("res" + res)   // logs value of res
})
```